# Node.js: module not found after installing it with npm -g

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules

I have installed the [tar](https://github.com/npm/node-tar)-module using

```
npm install -g tar
```

When I type

```
npm list -g --depth=0
```

I can see the entry `tar@6.1.0` in the module-tree, however when I try to require it in a js-file `const tar = require("tar")`, I get the error message

```
Uncaught Exception:
Error: Cannot find module 'tar'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: To use libraries in .js programs you must install them locally, not globally. Global modules are meant for command-line utilities.

Comment: Ah, ok, thanks a lot. So if I want to use a library in several projects, I will still have to install it locally for every single one of them?

Comment: Yes, you have to install it in each project you use. This also helps by saving the library in `package.json` and if you move it somewhere else a simple `npm install` brings the library with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're trying to use something installed globally in a local project. You should be able to use your libraries if you install them inside the project with `npm i tar`.

The reason we install something globally is for use during development on many projects. This way, we don't have to install a tool on every project. With something you want to use inside a projects code however, you should install it on a project level. This way everything that the project needs to work lives inside of the project itself.  You should see all  dependencies listed inside of your package.json file

Not gonna advocate you do this, but if you really want to include the globally installed library, you can do something like this:

```js
require('./../../.npm-global/lib/node_modules/tar'); // Relative path to library
```

Where you go up the file directory to your $HOME directory into the default global install location for node and bring it in. This is poor practice, please don't do it, but heres the info none-the-less.